# Using the WCF Service Application Template, where is the "service" info

Tags: wcf

I am using VS2010 and .NET 4.0. When I create a WCF Service Application, I can easily get my service up and running. However, I am unable to find the services information such as binding configuration and address etc. Where does the template store this information so that I can modify. I know I can add my own bindings and address in the config but I want to know what is the default binding WCF template is using and modify accordingly.

I apologize for the simple (dumb) question, but in 3.5 it was in the config upon using the template

Comment: Do you want to modify VS template itself? Is it your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not something being done by the template. The application is simply using  the default WCF configuration settings. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358768.aspx) for futher info.